# Get orderable fields - Django Rest

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a ReactJS table that uses fetch API to get the data from a Django server using Rest. I've defined the viewset to use OrderingFilter and specified the ordering_fields as so:

```
class RecipientViewSet(BaseViewSetClass):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = serializers.RecipientsSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
ordering_fields = (
    'id',
    'externalID',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
)
```

It works great, but I want to know if there's a method of getting from the ordering_fields from the server with fetch, so that I can add a sort icon only for the table headers that can be used to set the data's ordering.

I should add that in the Django REST Framework GUI I can click "Filters" button and view all possible filters for this viewset, and that's exactly what I want to get with ReactJS.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get the ordering fields out of the box via an API call, but you can always add an endpoint to return them:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route

class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ordering_fields = ('a', 'b')

    @list_route
    def get_ordering_fields(self, request):
        return self.ordering_fields
```

This way calling `/your_endpoint/get_ordering_fields/` will return the list of ordering fields defined in the class. You can apply any formatting before returning them if you wish.

Also keep in mind that this behavior can be implemented in a base or mixin class so it can be reused easily later.

See the [docs about list and detail routes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions).